# Fluentd: forwarding syslog events to sensu

Tags: syslog, fluentd, sensu

I'm trying to collect syslog messages from cisco equipment and send it to sensu for analysis and alerting. Is it possible/feasible with fluentd? If yes, could you please advise the way?
Thank you,
Alexei

Comment: Were you able to make any progress?  Are you pinging the Cisco equipment using their API or doing something else?

Comment: No progress at the moment. It looks like I have to write out_sensu myself :)

Comment: thanks for sharing - I'm looking at cisco devices but writing my own code for now

Comment: FYI, there is a handler for Sensu -> Fluentd (https://github.com/sensu/sensu-community-plugins/blob/master/handlers/notification/fluentd.rb)

Answer (score 0):

Sensu isn't a tool for log analysis - it is more for executing service checks (think Nagios-style monitoring). Fluentd can take syslog messages as input, but sensu isn't the proper output channel for analyzing those logs, and as it doesn't do alerting directly probably isn't the best choice for that either.